# How can I approximate $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \exp(-[(ak)^3+ibk])$ as an integral?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

As the title says I would like to know the solution of the following series,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \exp(-[(ak)^3+ibk]),$$
for $a\ll1$. I think this is too difficult to solve directly. Can we find an approximate solution by writing the sum as an integral? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $b \in \mathbb R$ is fixed. The sum and the integral tend to two different constants:
$$\lim_{a \downarrow 0} \int_0^\infty e^{-a k^3 - i b k} dk =
-\frac i b, \\
\lim_{a \downarrow 0} \sum_{k \geq 0} e^{-a k^3 - i b k} =
\frac 1 2 - \frac i 2 \cot \frac b 2.$$
The limit of the integral can be found by applying the steepest descent method. For the sum, suppose $\cot$ is the distribution understood in the sense of the principal value. The Fourier coefficients are
$$\frac 1 {2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-i k b} \cot \frac b 2 \, db =
-i \operatorname{sgn} k, \\
\frac 1 {2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-i k b} \delta(b) db =
\frac 1 {2 \pi}.$$
Then, in the distributional sense,
$$\lim_{a \downarrow 0} \sum_{k \leq 0} e^{a k^3 + i b k} =
\sum_{k \leq 0} e^{i k b} =
\frac 1 2 -
 \frac 1 2 \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} e^{i k b} \operatorname{sgn} k +
 \frac 1 2 \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} e^{i k b} = \\
\frac 1 2 - \frac i 2 \cot \frac b 2 +
 \pi \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} \delta(b - 2 \pi k).$$
When $b \neq 2 \pi k$, we have only the regular part.